# PostgreSQL Multiple Update

Tags: postgresql

I have a situation...
i have these columns - table X

```
 Product   Number  LastEditDate    GUID
 A         0       14.12.16        A1
 A         0       10.12.16        A2
 B         0       10.12.16        A3
 B         0       13.12.16        A4
 C         0       13.12.16        A5
 C         0       14.12.16        A6
```

Now, i need to put Number 1 to all products where the Date is the Max.
I was using this query:

```
update X set Number=0;
update X set Number=1 where LastEditDate in (select Max(LastEditDate) from X Group by Product);
```

So this will give me something like this:

```
Product    Number    LastEditDate
A          1         14.12.16
A          0         10.12.16
B          0         10.12.16
B          1         13.12.16
C          0         13.12.16
C          1         14.12.16
```

But, with my query, i have:
1;0;0;1;1;1; because 13.12.16 will be in that "select Max(LastEditDate) from X).
How to make like that, to have results: 1;0;0;1;0;1;???

Please help!

Comment: Sorry, there should be a "Group by Product"...i missed it...

Comment: Edit your question instead of use a comment.

Comment: Is there any unique ID for each row in this table;

Comment: Yes, there is a GUID

Comment: Could you add it to your table example?

Answer (score 1):

You should look for the pair `(product, lasteditdate)`:

```
update x 
set number = 1 
where (product, lasteditdate) in (
    select product, max(lasteditdate) 
    from x 
    group by product);
```

Comment: Thank you, i think this should work. I just don't understand why i didn't this before? :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can check it here: http://rextester.com/YVLK16496

```
with t1 as (
    select Product, Max(LastEditDate) as MaxDate from t group by Product
)
update t
set Number=1
from t1
where t.Product = t1.Product and t.LastEditDate = t1.MaxDate;
```

Comment: This also could work for me but i will try the "klin" answer. Thank you